# Which ideal body weight formula is used when choosing the ventilator's tidal volume?

Tags: mechanical-ventilation

When a patient is under mechanical ventilation, the ventilator's tidal volume is chosen based on the patient's ideal body weight.

However, there exist several [ideal body weight formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_body_weight#Ideal_body_weight). Do practitioners agree on one formula when used for mechanical ventilation, and if so which one?

If practitioners disagree, what are the upsides and downsides of each formula?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.